# jQuery JSON not passing data to Ci properly

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

The script below works as far as i can tell:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add').bind('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var add = $("#add").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "<?php echo site_url("home/jsonAddData"); ?>",
                data: add,
                json: {title_posted: true},
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.title_posted == true) { // true means data was successfully posted.
                        $("#success").append("Success").fadeIn(400);
                    } else if(data.title_posted == false) { // false means data failed to post.
                        $("#success").append('Failure').fadeIn(400);
                    }
               }
          });
       }
    });
});
</script>
```

The problem I'm experiencing with the code below is that the mysql insetion query just wont work. It creates the row in the table and auto-increments but for some odd reason it wont pass the 'var add' in the Javascript above to the Ci script below and perform an insertion in the db. Any thoughts or ideas?

```
<?php
class home extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function index() {
        $data = array();
        $data['lists'] = $this->displayList();
        $this->load->view('home', $data);
    }
    function displayList() {
        $str = '';
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM data");
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $b = '<input name="completed" type="checkbox" />';
            $a = $row->title . "<br>";
            $str .= $b.$a;
        }
        return $str;
    }
    function jsonAddData() {
        if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $title = $this->input->post('title');
        $query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO data (title) VALUES ('$title')");
        header('Content-type:application/json');
        if($query) echo json_encode(array('title_posted' => true));
        else echo json_encode(array('title_posted' => false));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: You have HTML-injection (cross-site scripting) and SQL-injection (database compromise) security holes in this script. HTML-encode all data you output to the page `htmlspecialchars($row->title)` and use parameterised queries to avoid this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
$.ajax({
...
data: {title: add}
```

Not just a string

Comment: Aw okay... so I need to pass it as a JSON element? It works though... thanks man!

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby You are not passing a "JSON element" - there is no such thing in Javascript and anyway, you are not sending [JSON](http://www.json.org/) to the server - you are passing an object, which will be converted to a URL-encoded query string so it can be used in POST request. If you want to pass a string, you would need to do `data: 'title='+escapeURIComponent(add)`. You should read the [`$.ajax` manual page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and learn about [HTTP POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) requests.

Comment: My bad, lol it's been a couple months since I've worked with Javascript. I'm still learning it. That's the format JSON uses though.... So it's just an object? And I know about POST and GET requests... I've been working with PHP since 2009.

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby JSON is a sub-set of Javascript's object literal syntax - for example the only parameter you passed to `$.ajax()` is an object literal, wrapped in `{}`. When the `data` property of this object is of a vector type (`object`), it is converted to a URL-encoded string, just like an HTML form submission - this is, after all, what you are mimicking with your request. When it is a scalar type like `string` or `number`, it is converted to a string and sent literally.